# Samsung Galaxy I9000 not detected by Odin in download mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

Samsung Galaxy GT-i9000 not detected by Odin in download mode.
I have Windows Vista and Kies is also installed on the P.C

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop kies. 
It has a thread in the background, so seach this in the taskmanager and stop the process.

Comment: Yep, Kies is usally the issue. However, it's worth adding that if you reboot into Download mode from the 4 way reboot menu there can be a lot of issues. It is better to switch the device off and boot into download mode with the Volume Down and Power combo.